# How to assign a Css class on an item based on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57f78yx1/1/

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".menu ul li").on("click", function(e) {
        alert($(this).index());
        var loe = $(this).index();
        $(".menu ul li:nth-child(" + loe + ")").addClass("activeLI");
    });
});
```

How can I modify so onclick set the style to the clicked item to `activeLI` and remove from the rest.

Comment: just use $('.activeLI').removeClass('activeLI'); and you must know that index start from 0  and nth-child start from 1  so var loe = ($(this).index()) + 1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the class from all `.menu ul li` and add it only to `$(this)` (the clicked element)

http://jsfiddle.net/57f78yx1/2/

```
$(function() {
    $(".menu ul li").on("click", function() {
        $(".menu ul li").removeClass("activeLI");
        $(this).addClass("activeLI");
    });
});
```

Comment: Also note, the outer function wrapper is a bit redundant: http://jsfiddle.net/57f78yx1/3/

Comment: That's because jsfiddle puts the Javascript in the `onload` function by default. Select `No wrap (in head)` from the menu and it won't work without the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I usually tend to do the following: I remove that class from all the li items and add it to the one I want:

```
$(function() {
    $(".menu ul li").on("click", function(e) {
        var loe = $(this).index();
        $(".menu ul li").each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("activeLI");
        });
        $(".menu ul li").eq(loe).addClass("activeLI");
    });
});
```

And a simpler version would be:

```
$(function() {
    $(".menu ul li").on("click", function(e) {
        $(".activeLI").removeClass("activeLI");
        $(this).addClass("activeLI");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add one to your `nt-child` like this: `loe = loe +1;`

see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/57f78yx1/5/

```
$(function() {
    $(".menu ul li").on("click", function(e) {
        alert($(this).index());
        var loe = $(this).index();
        loe = loe +1;
        $(".menu ul li:nth-child(" + loe + ")").addClass("activeLI");
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't that a really complicated way to do `$(this).addClass()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
var menuItem = $(".menu ul li a");
menuItem.click(function () {
    menuItem.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jcmorris/5h44o71b/